# Spacing too tight under a limit with two parts

Tags: math-mode, spacing, amsmath, alignment, vertical-spacing

I'm having troubles with a limit with two parts under it, as shown with this MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tensor}

\begin{document}

TEST
\begin{equation}
    p(t) \equiv \lim_{
        \substack{m \, \rightarrow \, \infty \\[1ex] \Delta t \, \rightarrow \, 0}
    } \tensor{p}{_m} = 1 - e^{- \lambda t}.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Preview:

[image]

How can I fix this vertical spacing issue?  And what should be a better spacing option for the `\\[1ex]` part in the code above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a `\mathstrut` to the first line of the \substack. On anotherhand, I wouldn't add a vertical spacing between the two lines:

```
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper, twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tensor}

\begin{document}

TEST
\begin{equation}
    p(t) \equiv \lim_{
        \substack{m \, \rightarrow \, \infty \mathstrut\\ \Delta t \, \rightarrow \, 0}
    } \tensor{p}{_m} = 1 - e^{- \lambda t}.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]